# Why am I getting a IOException from within System.IO.Pipes from Asynchronous Callbacks?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, asynchronous, system.io.file

I have my target .NET framework set to 4.0 which may be the reason that may be occurring since my program is crashing within the System.IO.Pipes resource. This error has never been able to be repeated and occurs up to a few times a week.

It crashes then restarts the service and there are two occurrences of this error. Both failing at the deepest point of `System.Threading._IOCompletionCallback.PerformIOCompletionCallback`

The first occurrence is at `System.IO.Pipes.NamedPipeServerStream.AsyncWaitForConnectionCallback`

In which this segment of code handles the object that *eventually calls within* that method.

```
protected override IAsyncResult BeginWaitForConnection(AsyncCallback callback, object state)
{
    try
    {
         return PipeServer.BeginWaitForConnection(callback, state);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
         PipeServer.Dispose();
         PipeServer = null;
         throw;
    }
}
```

`PipeServer` is of type `NamedPipeServerStream`.

The statement within the try/catch goes through just fine, but later the thread throws an error. I believe since it's an asynchronous call, it calls a method that later isn't around a try/catch (Within `System.IO.Pipes.NamedPipeServerStream` in this case).

It seems that the only way to solve this is to add a try/catch to the segment of code **within the `System.IO.Pipes.NamedPipeServerStream`** to handle whenever there's an exception, in which the resource hasn't be programmed to handle. **This isn't possible to do since these binaries are not modifiable.**

Below is the full error thrown in the logs from the first occurrence.

```
There are no context policies.
. Exiting!
System.IO.IOException: The handle is invalid.
at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
at System.Threading.EventWaitHandle.Set()
at System.IO.Pipes.NamedPipeServerStream.AsyncWaitForConnectionCallback(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* pOverlapped)
at System.Threading._IOCompletionCallback.PerformIOCompletionCallback(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* pOVERLAP)
```

The second occurance of the IOException is at
`System.IO.Pipes.PipeStream.AsyncPSCallback`, which is also a method that eventually uses a asynchronous callback.

The given code where the the asynchronous callback is found is used in the below segment of code.

```
public override IAsyncResult BeginRead(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count, AsyncCallback callback, object state)
{
     return NamedPipeStream.BeginRead(buffer, offset, count, callback, state);
}
```

`NamedPipeStream` is of type `PipeStream`.

After awhile this is the full error that is connected to that statement.

```
There are no context policies.
. Exiting!
System.IO.IOException: The handle is invalid.
at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
at System.Threading.EventWaitHandle.Set()
at System.IO.Pipes.PipeStream.AsyncPSCallback(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* pOverlapped)
at System.Threading._IOCompletionCallback.PerformIOCompletionCallback(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* pOVERLAP)
```

To my understanding, each of these called object types, `NamedPipeServerStream` and `PipeStream` uses `System.IO.Pipes` and has try/catches around them. I think that since this is an asynchronous call, a thread is created to handle there function for later. Since they're their own threads, that would explain why it isn't getting caught in the try/catches when it is initially called. This would also explain why the errors are not tracing back to the statements within the try/catch.

Which leaves me with the question, is there anyway to avoid or catch this exception in order to prevent the program from crashing?

Comment: Please check out results of following search https://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23+exception+handling+AsyncCallback and [edit] post to provide [MCVE] - in particular how you implement `callback` handlers.

Comment: I have search a lot of this issue, but have found a solution. The callback is handled by calling a function within the project. It shouldn't be within the callback implementation anyway since the error doesn't trace to any self-programmed code.